# Image Upload preview not working Chrome

Tags: image-processing, google-chrome, file-upload, uploading

This is code only Compatibility IE, FF but not working chrome and safari. please suggest me  a way for that.

```
<h3>Choose an image:</h3>   
    <input type='file'  onchange="document.images[0].src=getPath(this);"  />


<h3>preview</h3>    
    <img src="#" alt="your image"    /> 

<script type='text/javascript'>

function getPath(input){
   if(input.files && input.files[0]){
      return input.files[0].getAsDataURL();
   }
 return input.value || "No file selected";
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
<html><body>

<h3>Choose an image:</h3>   
    <form><input type='file'  onchange="readURL(this);"  /></form>


<h3>preview</h3>    
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image"    /> 

<script type='text/javascript'>

var reader = new FileReader(); 
reader.onload = function(e) {
  document.images[0].src  = e.target.result; 
};

function readURL(input){ 
   if(input.files && input.files[0]){
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
   }
   else {
     document.images[0].src = input.value || "No file selected";
   }
}

</script>

</body></html>
```

Comment: I fixed one line but the I think it will only work when the browser is pointed at a local html file.  Unfortunately I don't know how to do the equivalent of "readAsDataURL" on IE.